# Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled in Angular

Tags: angular

I changed tailwind.min.css from href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" to local storage href="./././libs/dave2-shared/src/lib/CSS/tailwind.min.css" path but I get **“Refused to apply style from 'http://ui_fb3.sym-tech.loc:4200/libs/dave2-shared/src/lib/CSS/tailwind.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.”** error in console in Angular.

I tried changing type="text/css" and type="text/html" but nothing works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Setting</title>
    <base href="/setting/" />
    <link href="./././shared/src/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">        
  </head>
  <body>
    <ng-root></ng-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to be outside of root..? That file probably is not served so you probably can’t actually request it in the browser.. (did you try..?)

Comment: tailwind.min.css is in "libs/dave2-shared/src/lib/CSS/tailwind.min.css" folder and index.html is inside apps/ng-admin/src. Sorry what are you suggesting to try. I didn't get that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Angular bundles your application for serving, it does not know, that it needs to include your css file (and it probably falls back to index.html, when it cannot find the file in the path indicated - that's the error with the incorrect MIME type, because index.html does not have the correct type for a stylesheet).

Try to add the path to the css file in angular.json - in the styles section (projects -> $project name$ -> architect -> build -> options -> styles).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have multiple projects under projects. Do I need to add it to every project and is there any other way/better way?

Comment: There are 4 ways, that come to my mind, to include a css file - 1) access it from a remote server (the way you had it before) 2) add it to styles list in angular.json - for all the projects, that will be using it 3) add it stylesUrls lists of components, that will be using it, or 4) import it in css files of all the components, that will be using it

Answer (score -1):

I know its late. I faced this issue when I tried to use fontawesome v6.2.0, following the steps in FontAwesome page. They says that you need put this link:
`<link href="/src/assets/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the `<head>` tag in the index.html file.

I fixed it, adding the css reference in the style.css file. Like this:

```
@import "../src/assets/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.min.css";
```

Hope this works for you!